# Can I use Bulk API to automate insertion of Knowledge Data Category Assignment?

Tags: knowledge, bulk-api, bulk, data-category, data-category-selection

When I try to execute command sf bulk upsert for Knowledge__DataCategorySelection I receive an error `No create/update access for object:Knowledge__DataCategorySelection`.

```
sf data upsert bulk -s Knowledge__DataCategorySelection -f ART_CAT_1.csv -w 500 -i Id 
 ›   Warning: @salesforce/cli update available from 2.30.8 to 2.34.7.
Running bulk upsert request... done
Error (1): InvalidJob : No create/update access for object:Knowledge__DataCategorySelection
```

Does this mean Knowledge__DataCategorySelection is not supported for the Bulk API completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we can use bulk API but we can't leverage the `sf data upsert bulk` command.

This command always uses `upsert` operation and it is not possible to change to `insert` operation.

Knowledge__DataCategorySelection object, instead, doesn't support update operation, thus, it also doesn't support upsert operation and supports only `insert` and `delete`.

This is not obvious but it is technically possible to leverage Bulk API command but not through `sf` CLI tool.

We just need to select `insert` instead of `upsert` operation

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

One important note that we assume that only a single knowledge article exists with a given UrlName since if you publish an article and edit it as draft, you might have two articles with the same UrlName and this would break the upload process since Knowledge__kav doesn't have standard unique external Id field and doesn't support adding custom unique external Id field.